# How I priorize program hotkeys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, globalmenu

I'm play an game and need the F10, but when I press it in-game it show the menu context, how I priorize the program hotkeys?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not quite the full solution, but as a temporary fix you can change the F10 shortcut to something less ubiquitous using CCSM

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

In the 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin' options the keyboard shortcut is 'Key to open the first panel menu'.

Comment: Thanks. Really isn't the full solution, but I think will solve my problem by now :)